# Symmetric formulation for the heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

**Originally posted on MSE**

---

Consider the heat equation on a domain $U$: $$\partial_t u - \operatorname{div}(A\,\nabla u)=f$$

with $u(0)=0, u=0$ on the boundary of the domain of definition. Consider a test function $v=v(x,t)$, and perform the following operations:

1. integrate the strong formulation from $0$ to $t$: $$u(t)-\int_0^t \operatorname{div}(A\,\nabla u)(\tau)\,d\tau=\cdots$$
2. integrate in space and take a convolution product with $v$: $$\int_0^T\int_U u(t,x) \, dx v(T-t,x) \, dt-\int_0^T\int_U\int_0^t \operatorname{div}(A \, \nabla u)(\tau,x) \, d\tau v(T-t,x) \,dx \, dt=\cdots$$
3. apply, in space, the divergence theorem:
   $$\int_U (u(\cdot,x)*v(\cdot,x))(T) \, dx +\int_U \left( \left( \int_0^\cdot  (A \, \nabla u)(\tau,x) \, d\tau\right) * \nabla v(\cdot,x) \right)(T) \, dx = \cdots$$

Now, if $A$ is constant in time, we get a symmetric formulation. In fact, doing some simple change of variables yields:

$$\left(\left (\int_0^\cdot  \nabla u(\tau,x) \, d\tau\right ) * \nabla v(\cdot,x) \right)(T) = \left(\left (\int_0^\cdot  \nabla v(\tau,x) \, d\tau\right ) * \nabla u(\cdot,x) \right)(T)$$

This also shows that as soon as $A$ is not constant in time, symmetry cannot be expected. Yet, the authors of [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/717595) very short paper seem to claim this is the case, in the first page.

> Is it the paper or my understanding that is wrong? Maybe there exists a choice of spaces for $A$ on one hand, and $u,v$ on the other, to make the claim true?

---

*Context*

Solving the heat equation with a space-time method, naturally yields non-symmetric linear systems to be solved, because of the presence of the time derivative. However, applying the convolution operator, one could hope to make those systems symmetric (albeit dense). This might yield increased computational efficiency.